# Ms access adding data to tables via forms

Tags: database, vba

I am currently using ms access forms to view data used within tables I have created, to make it more user friendly.

Tables are listed below:

- tblCourse
- tblEmployee
- tblReason
- tblTraining

The training table is populated by using the primary keys from the other tables.

Fields listed below:

- ID
- EmployeeID
- Date
- CourseID
- Other
- ReasonID

I want to be able to add to the tblTraining table using text boxes and combo boxes on the ms access form. However, the issue I am having is that only a number format can be added to the table. Is there a way that I can insert text and it would find the primary linked to it and adds it to the table.

For example..

The text fields that I have on the form are:

- txtTrainingID
- cbbCourse (shows a list of all the courses we have available)
- txtDate
- txtFirstName
- txtSurname
- cbbReason (shows a list of the reason employee is taking the training)
- txtOther

and the fields on the Training table is listed above.

Here is an example of the code I used to add employees to the tblEmployee table:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click()

If Me.txtEmployeeID.Tag & "" = "" Then

CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblEmployee(EmployeeID, FirstName, Surname) " & _
"VALUES (" & Me.txtEmployeeID & " , '" & Me.txtFirstName & "', '" & Me.txtSurname & "')"

MsgBox ("Employee has been added.")

Else

CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblEmployee " & _
" SET EmployeeID = " & Me.txtEmployeeID & _
", FirstName = '" & Me.txtFirstName & "'" & _
", Surname = '" & Me.txtSurname & "'" & _
" WHERE EmployeeID = " & Me.txtEmployeeID.Tag

MsgBox ("Employee has been updated.")

End If

btnClear_Click

Me.txtEmployeeID.SetFocus

Me.subformEmployee.Form.Requery

End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: First, why not use a bound recordsource form to handle insert and update needs? Second, combo boxes should be bound to hidden IDs but show its row's text value to the user (e.g., show *course name* but bound to *course ID* using a query [rowsource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/combobox-rowsource-property-access)). This way combo box will always be a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your tables are structured like below

tblCourse:
ID autonumber - PRIMARY KEY

tblEmployee:
ID autonumber- PRIMARY KEY

tblReason:
ID autonumber - PRIMARY KEY

tblTraining:
ID autonumber - PRIMARY KEY
EmployeeID long integer - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblEmployee(ID)
CourseID long integer - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblCourse(ID)
ReasonID long integer - FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tblReason(ID)

if this is correct, then to answer your question, no, you cannot add text to these fields on the table. It has to be a number due to the relationship structure you have in place.